# As a US Green Card holder, California resident and German citizen, is investing in European investment funds permitted?

Tags: united-states, investing, california, germany

I am a resident of California and a citizen of Germany (green card holder). Is it permitted for me to have money invested in European investment funds? I was told that I'm only allowed to invest in shares which I then directly own.

Comment: Who told you? What reason did they give? US law? German law? European law? There are some restrictions, but none like that as far as I know.